# Invertibility of blocks in a block orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

Given a block matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}A_{11} \quad A_{12} \\ A_{21}\quad A_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ that is real orthogonal, where $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ are square matrices, I am asked to show that $A_{11}$ is invertible if and only if $A_{22}$ is.

What I've done so far:

From orthogonality, one concludes that the inverse of $A$ is $A^T$, which is writable in block form as $\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}^T \quad A_{21}^T \\ A_{12}^T\quad A_{22}^T\end{pmatrix}$. Ordinary multiplication of $A$ with $A^T$  (i.e. $AA^T + I$) helps us conclude that $$
A_{11}A^T_{11} + A_{12}A_{12}^T = I = A_{21}A_{21}^T + A_{22} A_{22}^T \\
A_{11} A_{21}^T + A_{12} A_{22}^T = 0 = A_{21} A_{11}^T + A_{22} A_{12}^T 
$$

Now, there is no expression involving $A_{11}$ and $A_{22}$ coming together, hence I am unsure what to do next.

Comment: If you multiply from the right ($AA^T$), shouldn't it be $A_{11}A^T_{11}+A_{12}A^T_{12}=I$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I shall make some minor changes. Yes, they have been made now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume $A_{11}$ is invertible. Then the second line can be changed to
$$A^T_{21}=-A^{-1}_{11}A_{12}A^T_{22}$$ Plugging this into the first gives 
$$I=-A_{21}A^{-1}_{11}A_{12}A^T_{22}+A_{22}A^T_{22}=(-A^{-1}_{11}A_{21}A_{12}+A_{22})A^T_{22}$$
The other directions works the same way.

Comment: The second line does not exactly change like how it's been given, but I followed what you tried to do, and got the logic and answer, so thank you for your answer. If you can correct the errors then I can upvote this answer.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг You're right of course, done so.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your answer, once again!